# Fourier transform of quotient

Tags: fourier-transform

I would like to know the Inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{36}{37-\frac53\cos(2\pi f)}$, where $f$ is the frequency. How does one handle this quotient?

Comment: What's your definition of the fourier transform? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to format your expression, please correct it if I misunderstood it in some way. - And please tell us what you have done and where you get stuck so we might offer help adressing your problem.